# Хочу вызывать много картинок по URL

Tags: android, android-studio, picasso

public class Library extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ImageView image1,image2;
String url1 ="";
String url2 ="";


@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.library);
    image1=findViewById(R.id.image1);
    loadImageFromUrl(url1);
    image2=findViewById(R.id.image2);
    loadImageFromUrl(url2);
}

private void loadImageFromUrl (String url) {
    Picasso.with(this).load(url1).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(image1, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess () {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError () {

                }

            });
}
```

}

Хочу вызывать много картинок по URL, но в этом коде можно реализовать только одну картинку.

Comment: Одна из самых упоротых вещей, что я видел

Comment: Хоспаде, сделайте массив/лист с картинками и все

Comment: Используйте для таких вещей `RecyclerView`, что вам еще сказать.

Comment: Во первых я только начал программировать так что как вы говорите "самые упоротые" вещи свойственны молодому программисту без любого технического образования. А во вторых не могла бы Ваша милость снизойти и написать как правильно.

Comment: http://www.fandroid.info/primer-ispolzovaniya-cardview-i-recyclerview-v-android/
Тут написано как использовать RecylerView. Вкратце ты определяешь вид своей карточки, в данном случае у тебя будет картинка. Добавляешь ссылки на свои картинки в массив List или ArrayList, как удобно. Передаешь этот лист в адаптер. А там привязываешь ссылку на картинку и ее отображение в методе onBindViewHolder( то есть твой метод loadImageFromUrl должен быть там). Подробнее в статье

Comment: Я не хочу делать RecycleView я хочу вызвать несколько картинок

Comment: а много это сколько, 5, 10, 100, 1000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно просто вывести несколько картинок на экран. Метод .into в Picasso определяет куда вы хотите добавить картинку

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.library);
    image1=findViewById(R.id.image1);
    loadImageFromUrl(url1, image1);
    image2=findViewById(R.id.image2);
    loadImageFromUrl(url2, image2);
}

private void loadImageFromUrl (String url, ImageView image) {
    Picasso.with(this).load(url).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .into(image);
}
```